# Display alert message and redirect after click on accept

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a page with links to reports. Whenever somebody clicks on one report, they can download the excel file. However, sometimes there are no fields to make a report; in that case, I want to display an alert message and after they click on "accept", they get redirected to the main panel. When they click on the report, they go to a controller that uses a `switch` to get the data. If there's no data, the model returns `FALSE`; so at the end of the controller, I check:

```
if ($result_array != FALSE)
    to_excel($result_array->result_array(), $xls,$campos);
else {
    echo "<script>alert('There are no fields to generate a report');</script>";
    redirect('admin/ahm/panel');
}
```

If I get rid of `redirect('admin/ahm/panel');` then the alert works, but it moves the user to the page that was supposed to generate the excel file. But if I use the redirect, the controller moves the user to the main panel without showing the alert.

Comment: Redirect first, notifying the page you redirect to that an alert needs to be shown.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
echo "<script>
alert('There are no fields to generate a report');
window.location.href='admin/ahm/panel';
</script>";
```

and get rid of `redirect` line below.

You were mixing up two different worlds.

Comment: There's a problem with this. It just add the url that I want to go to to the current url. But it doesn't redirect. I even tried using the whole url (with http://) and still it doesn't redirect; just adds it to the current url and I get stuck on an endless alert loop.

Comment: edited. changed `+=` to `=`. Earlier I specifically added to current url because I thought you wanted it. But anyways, should work now.

Comment: This is not safe, disabling javascript would let further processing continue.

Comment: what is "window.location.href='admin/ahm/panel';"?

Answer (score 7):

**use this code to redirect the page**

```
echo "<script>alert('There are no fields to generate a report');document.location='admin/ahm/panel'</script>";
```

Answer (score 3):

Combining CodeIgniter and JavaScript:

```
//for using the base_url() function
$this->load->helper('url');

echo "<script type='javascript/text'>";
echo "alert('There are no fields to generate a report');"
echo "window.location.href = '" . base_url() . "admin/ahm/panel';"
echo "</script>";
```

**Note:** The `redirect()` function automatically includes the `base_url` path that is why it wasn't required there.

Answer (score 1):

The `redirect` function cleans the output buffer and does a `header('Location:...');` redirection and exits script execution. The part you are trying to echo will never be outputted.

You should either notify on the download page or notify on the page you redirect to about the missing data.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<script>
window.location.href='admin/ahm/panel';
alert('There are no fields to generate a report');
</script>";
```

Try out this way it works...

First assign the window with the new page where the alert box must be displayed then show the alert box.

Answer (score 0):

that worked but try it this way.

```
echo "<script>
alert('There are no fields to generate a report');
window.location.href='admin/ahm/panel';  
</script>";
```

alert on top then location next

Answer (score 0):

This way it works`

```
   if ($result_array)
    to_excel($result_array->result_array(), $xls,$campos);
else {
    echo "<script>alert('There are no fields to generate a report');</script>";
    echo "<script>redirect('admin/ahm/panel'); </script>";
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

*//functions.php:*

```
    <?php
function fx_alert_and_redirect($msg, $page){
    **echo "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>Login...</head><body><script type='text/javascript'>alert(\"" .$msg . "\");window.location.href=\"$page\";</script></body></html>";**
    

}
?>
```

*//process_login-form.php:*

```
<?php require_once '../app/utils/functions.php'; ?>

<?php

// ...

fx_alert_and_redirect("Mauvais nom d'usager ou mot de passe!", "../index.php?page=welcome");

?>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).