# Redirecting to a php URL after showing JavaScript alert

Tags: javascript, php, alert

I am trying to work on a module where there is an option to show the JavaScript alert and then it should redirect to a php $url. My script is attached below.

```
$url1=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$url = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $url1);

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Quote Emailed Successfully.');
url = '<?php echo $url; ?>';

window.location='url';
</script>";
```

It is showing the alert but it's not redirecting.

Comment: possible duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/a/11869779/9223416

Comment: use window.location.href

Comment: This is a fail to begin with, because it relies on a Referrer to figure out where to redirect to - so it will not work for any users that have their browser configured not to send one for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> url = '<?php echo $url; ?>';
> ```

You can't nest `<?php ... ?>` blocks.

Just use the variable. You are in a double quoted PHP string literal, so it will be interpolated.

```
url = '$url';
```

> ```
> window.location='url';
> ```

You are trying to redirect to the URL ***url*** instead of the value of the `url` variable.

Remove the quotes.

```
window.location = url;
```

Answer (score -1):

check this

```
<script>
   $url1=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
   $url = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $url1);

   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Quote Emailed 
   Successfully.')";
   url = '<?php echo $url; ?>';

   window.location='url';
</script>";
```

Comment: This is an unreadable mess. I've no idea what you are trying to suggest. Try adding an explanation and formatting your code.

Comment: you have error in this line echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Quote Emailed Successfully.');------please use " this double cot in last then check

Comment: What error? What line? There are 4 lines in the answer.

Comment: you have error in this line echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Quote Emailed Successfully.'); please use double cot in last then check

Answer (score -1):

You are setting **window.location** to the value **'url'**. Notice the quotes. You should use the declared variable url. Just remove the quotes, as shown below.

```
$url1=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$url = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $url1);

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Quote Emailed Successfully.');
var url = '<?php echo $url; ?>';

window.location= url;
</script>";
```

Comment: Re edit: there's more wrong with the code then that.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$url1=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$url = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $url1);

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Quote Emailed Successfully.');var url = '" . $url; . "';window.location=url;</script>";
```

or you can also do it like

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Quote Emailed Successfully.');
window.location='" . $url; . "';</script>";
```

Answer (score -1):

you should use location.href to redirect to php url e.g

```
alert("alert your text ");
location.href = <?php echo $url_name; ?> ;
```

Comment: No, assigning a string to the `location` object is fine.

Answer (score -1):

If you doesn't need to confirm the redirection then using this script might help

```
<script>
alert('Your message');
setTimeout(locate,3000);
function locate()
{
    window.location.replace('PHP URL');
}
</script>
```

If you need to confirm the redirection

```
if (confirm('Go to PHP URL')) 
{
    window.location.replace('PHP URL'); }
else 
{ 
    /* Do Something Else*/ 
}
```